# Custom wordpress rewrite rule = reusable tags taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, tags, taxonomy, posts

OK, the idea is simple. Every wordpress site is uses categories and tags taxonomies by default in the following manner:
category taxonomy slug = wpsite.com/parent-cat-slug/sub-cat-slug/
tags taxonomy slug = wpsite.com/tag/tag-slug

In many cases, a category has a set of tags associated with posts within that category. If for some reason the author associates a post to multiple categories, then that same tag is carried along with it. I think we all understand that.

Here's the problem, better demonstrated through an example:
Category 1 = **politics**
Category 2 = **business**
Tag = **corruption**

If I am under the "politics" category, reading a post tagged with corruption, and click on the tag link, it will take me to **wpsite.com/tag/corruption** and give me a list of posts that have that tag, all of which may or may NOT belong to the same category.

**WHAT IF WE CAN DO THIS:**
if you click on the tag "corruption" from inside the category "politics", the permalinks would point to **wpsite.com/politics/corruption** only displaying post tagged with "corruption" from that category instead of a site wide list?

This method is used in the Guadian newspaper:
http://www.guardian.co.uk/culture (top category - hover your mouse over the "Latest video, audio and galleries" post links, each has the sub-taxonomy under the top gallery, and does NOT point **guardian.co.uk/video** or **audio** etc as demonstrated below)
[http://www.guardian.co.uk/*culture*/**video**/2012/mar/24/vincent-van-gogh-house-london-sale-video](http://www.guardian.co.uk/%2aculture%2a/%2a%2avideo%2a%2a/2012/mar/24/vincent-van-gogh-house-london-sale-video)

This is a great way of classifying and associating post formats or tags, in a human readable way, which is much better than the generic wpsite.com/tag/tag-slug structure.

So, is there a way for us to achieve this in wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, yes, you can do that in WordPress. But there will be a whole lot works to achieve that.

To filter your category archive to show certain tags, simply you can go to `http://site.com/?category_name=politics&tag=corruption`, that would work. But what if we want to use permalink instead of that old query string kind of URL? Well, we can add new $wp_rewrite->rules for that.

But it's not just it, you will have to filter each `get_category_link()` and `get_term_link()` functions to change your tags and category links to meet your needs. E.g, for tag links displayed on a category, we need them to point exactly to tag/category.

Well, that's the clue. As I said, it can be done.